# how to run a CRM workflow when a new member added to the team or member removed from team?

Tags: .net, dynamics-crm-2015

I want to execute a workflow when a new member added to the owner team in CRM or an existing member removed from team. I am using CRM online. When the team structure is changed in CRM I want to replicate the same in share point using custom workflow.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot trigger workflows when related entities are added on a record, which in this case a team member would be. Here is one way to achieve this by not moving the entire logic to a plugin.

You could use a plugin on the entity "Team" for the message "Add Member" or "Remove Member" and then execute your workflow using [ExecuteWorkflowRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.crm.sdk.messages.executeworkflowrequest.aspx) sdk method. This way you could still have the workflow that you intend to use and trigger it from within a plugin or you could just move the business process logic into the plugin itself.